# Where can I find documentation on the OutlookServicesClient API?

Tags: web, service, outlook, exchange-server

Does any know where to look for documentation for the OutlookServicesClient API? I have found bits and pieces.

Comment: Please note that searching for external resources is considered offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "OutlookServicesClient API" means https://outlook.office.com/api or https://outlook.office365.com/api (the so called "Outlook REST API") then you can find the whole documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api).

There is a O[utlook Mail REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetAttachments) subsection for example which currently cover the following:

> Get messages | Synchronize messages | Create and send messages | Reply
>   or reply all to messages | Forward new or drafted messages | Update
>   messages | Delete messages | Move or copy messages | Manage Focused
>   Inbox | Manage @-Mentions (preview) | Unsubscribe (preview) | Get all
>   mailbox settings | Get auto reply settings | Update auto reply
>   settings | Get MailTips (preview) | Get attachments | Create
>   attachments | Delete attachments | Get folders | Synchronize folders |
>   Create folders | Update folders | Delete folders | Move or copy
>   folders

and also contains samples.

Comment: Thank guys for the information - I already knew about these document references but I was not referring to the new REST API but to the .NET Native OutlookServicesClient API. As the OutlookServicesClient API used to the ExchangeClient. It does look like the semantics of the OutlookServiecsClient API does follow the Office 365 REST API. I was looking for express documents that describe OutlookServicesClient but such documentation does not seem to exist; I have only found a weak cache of sample code.